# Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM: virtual tables / views - is it possible?

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

I have a table events, where I log different kind of events, e.g. login, register, etc. This is based on the `type` column.

I'd like to have different models (or any other suitable solution) for each event type, like `EventLogin`. Thus it would look like I have different "tables" for each event type, even though they are saved in the same table.

**Edit:** of course, I don't want to think about it every time, i.e. I would like to do `EventLogin->where("user_id", "=", $user->id)` and not have to worry about remembering to do `->where("type", "=", "login")`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think this can interest you :

http://vimeo.com/53183075 (morphMany() / morphTo() usage near 7'00)

Otherwise, @TheShiftExchange is right, i up him.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't pasted much code :), but this is it, polymorphic relations! I'll use that!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible?

Yes.

Just have different model files. You'll need to set the table name, since your model name wont be the same:

```
protected $table = 'your_table';
```

Otherwise it will work as a normal table.

You can apply this same principle to forms. Rather than have one model for each table, you can instead have one model for each form - and keep all the form logic in one place.

Comment: I guess my problem was not obvious enough, I've edited my question (see the edit part) as this is not the solution (yet).